# Gnuplot histogram (smooth freq) max position

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

When plotting with `smooth freq`, how do I get the x-position that corresponds to the y-max? Given a set of data:

```
#data.dat
7.20051
7.65602
7.87180
8.64177
8.92575
8.65913
8.98814
9.45199
8.40334
8.75102
8.65440
8.21088
8.59719
8.23259
8.34794
8.41658
7.67074
8.44228
8.54347
9.04961
9.18177
....
```

I've tried the following:

```
gnuplot
binwidth=0.1
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width) + binwidth/2.0
set terminal unknown
plot 'data.dat' u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq w l
show variables all
```

GPVAL_Y2_MAX = 6051.0 is the max y-value (peak) that I want, but how do I get the corresponding x-value? Using `stats` doesn't allow for `smooth freq` and I don't want to pre-process the data into bins. Is there a way to get the x-value using gnuplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use gnuplot to preprocess that data.  Let's suppose that your data looks like

```
7.20051
7.65602
7.87180
8.64177
8.92575
8.65913
8.98814
9.45199
8.40334
8.75102
8.65440
8.21088
8.59719
8.23259
8.34794
8.41658
7.67074
8.44228
8.54347
9.04961
9.18177
```

Then running the first part of your script

```
binwidth=0.1
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width) + binwidth/2.0
plot 'data.dat' u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq w l
```

produces

[image]

where we see a peak of 3 at 8.45 and 8.65.

Now, we can't use the stats command to find this on the provided data, but we can use it on some pre-processed data where gnuplot can do this pre-processing.

```
set table "tempfile"
plot 'data.dat' u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq
unset table
```

The set table command causes gnuplot to push the plot analysis to a file instead of drawing a plot with it.  The result is that the file *tempfile* now contains the binned data:

```
# Curve 0 of 1, 14 points
# Curve title: "$k u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0)"
# x y type
 7.25  1  i
 7.65  2  i
 7.85  1  i
 8.25  2  i
 8.35  1  i
 8.45  3  i
 8.55  2  i
 8.65  3  i
 8.75  1  i
 8.95  2  i
 9.05  1  i
 9.15  1  i
 9.45  1  i
 8.65  1  u
```

Notice the **i** and **u** in that last column.  The **i** indicates in range data and the **u** indicates out of range data.  The smooth options almost always add one final point like that which is out of range.  We just have to tell the stat command to ignore that one.

```
stat "tempfile" u 1:(strcol(3) eq 'i'?$2:1/0)
```

Here we use the stat command to analyze the temporary file using the first column and the second column only if the third column (read as a string by the strcol function) is equal to **i**.

Now, the value of the STATS_max_y and STATS_pos_max_y variables are 3 and 8.65 respectively.  This indicates the second peak.